Best type of concrete to pour in molds for garden spheres (16" and 19" diameter spheres)?
I purchased two molds to make some concrete spheres for my front yard. I am asking for advice on what type of ratio or off the shelf type of concrete mix I can buy in order to create the smoothest looking finish. I'm of the thought that avoiding aggregate in the mix will help me achieve this but I want to ensure they're strong enough to last for many years.
Not sure if this matters but I live in southern California where summer temperatures can reach 124°F. After they cure for thirty days, I plan on painting these spheres to help preserve them. Spalling seems to be an issue here with the extreme heat over time. Just wanted to provide this info in case it was important for determining the best concrete mix for my specific application.
Ball Sphere Mold:

